# Use objects in mat-autocomplete

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I working on a simple Angular translation app.
Is there a way to display both values from an object? In this case, I would like to display the Swedish and English words at the same time.

It works fine with the autocomplete but I have issues displaying both languages at the same time.

I attach a screenshot that hopefully explains a little more what I'm trying to do.

Thank you!

[image]

My code so far ->

```js
export class ToolsComponent implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options = [];
  filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((val) => {
        return this.filter(val || "");
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
    // call the service which makes the http-request
    
    return this.searchService.getData().pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.filter((option: { swedish: any }) => {
          return option.swedish.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0;
        })
      )
      
    );
  
  }

}
export class SearchService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  opts = [];
  
  getData() {
    return this.opts.length ?
      of(this.opts) :
      this.http.get<any>('./assets/data/data.json').pipe(tap(data => this.opts = data))
  }

}
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "swedish": "Stol",
      "english": "Chair"
  
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "swedish": "Mus",
      "english": "Mouse"

    },
    ]
```

```html
          <mat-form-field class="columnTranslator" appearance="outline">
                <mat-label class="inputTranslator">Enter text</mat-label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Pick one"
                  aria-label="Number"
                  matInput
                  [formControl]="myControl"
                  [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
                  <mat-option
                    *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" 
                    [value]="option.swedish">
                    {{ option.swedish }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
              </mat-form-field>
```